# How to give equations in Apache pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am trying to get a value from this equation

```
--counted gives the total row count in a file
samplecount = counted*(10/100);
```

How to sample data according to this

```
--Load data
examples = LOAD '/home/sreeveni/myfiles/PE/USCensus1990New.csv' ;

--Group data
groupedByUser = group examples all;

--count no of lines in the file
 counted = FOREACH groupedByUser generate COUNT(examples) ;

--sampling
sampled = SAMPLE examples counted*(10/100);
store sampled into '/home/sreeveni/myfiles/OUT/samplesout';
```

Showing error in above line

> Invalid scalar projection: counted : A column needs to be projected
>   from a relation for it to be used as a scalar

Please advice.

Am I doing anything wrong.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: I am getting an error in that line.
Invalid scalar projection: counted : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar

Comment: can you post complete code starting from loading the file.

Comment: sure. will update the question

Answer (score 2):

i guess sample works with a number between [0,1]. In your case, its exceeding the required value. If you want just 10% of the data, pass 0.1 directly and to get that in a code, find this percentage in a FOREACH statement only.

Comment: yes it works with numbers.but that values is a custom param for me where user will be telling the %

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to generate a sample of "examples" with 10% of the total number of rows, all you have to do is:

```
    SAMPLE examples 0.1;
```

Read the documentation for SAMPLE command [here](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.1/basic.html#sample).

Comment: yes it works with numbers.but that values is a custom param for me where user will be telling the % value